# accessing mvc modelstate properties from javascript, array property called ""

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have my API returning a bad request with a error object with a modelstate property:

[image]

that I am catching in my javascript such as: (service.saveRegistration is a function that executes the request)

```
 service.saveRegistration($scope.registration).then(function (response) {

       //success

    },
     //failure
     function (response) {
         //error response logic here             

         //goal is to update the error message to my client
         $scope.message = "Failed to register user because: " + <insert error message here here>;
     });
};
```

From the sample I am following this is supposedly how to get the info from the model state object returned from the server side code:

```
         var errors = [];
         for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
             console.log(response.data.modelState[key][0]);
             for (var i = 0; i < response.data.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                 errors.push(response.data.modelState[key][i]);
             }
         }
         $scope.message = "Failed to register user because: " + errors.join(' ');
```

But this is returning nothing for me. For simplicity sake I just want to access 
the 0 index of the ModelState Array but I am having trouble since its named "". How can I access it?

> response.data.modelState.""[0]

Comment: what are you returning from your angular service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case-sensitive. Notice that in the response, the `ModelState` property begins with capital "M".

Try:

```
for (var key in response.data.ModelState)
```